# how can I publish my software for Ubuntu like extras or partner repositories, but closed source

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, proprietary

I want to publish my software (e.g. some are drivers which means they are `.so` or `.a`, some are applications) as closed source.

I've rented a server, so that people can download my software from there. But I want people to be able to install my software using `apt-get`. I found that extras or partner repositories may be the way to do that.

Could anyone give me some advice on how I can publish my software as extras or partner repositories? I know PPAs need to published as open source.

Comment: If you already have a server, just host a repository on it. That's the simplest way here.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository) went through step by step to create a ubuntu repository on your own server.

Some key points:

#### 1.Set up web server

- Install Apache2

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install apache2
  sudo apache2ctl -k restart
  ```
- setup configure

  ```
  cat /Install Apache2/000-default.conf
  ```

  make sure `DocumentRoot /var/www` is right

#### 2. Create a deb package

- build an executable named `test`

  ```
  mkdir -p test/usr/local/bin
  cp test test/usr/local/bin
  vi /test/DEBIAN/control
  ```

  enter

  ```
  Package: test  
  Version: 1.0  
  Section: custom  
  Priority: optional  
  Architecture: all  
  Essential: no  
  Installed-Size: 1024  
  Maintainer: me 
  Description: Print hello on the screen
  ```

  run

  ```
  dpkg-deb --build petbotTest
  ```

#### 3. put deb into special directory tree for `apt-get` to know

```
    cd /var/www
    mkdir -p repo/ubuntu_14.04
    cp /your_path/test.deb /var/www/repo/ubuntu_14.04
    dpkg-scanpackages ubuntu_14.04 /dev/null | gzip -9c > ubuntu_14.04/Packages.gz
```

#### 4. for download

- In your client computer:

  ```
  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://YOUR_SERVER_IP/repo ubuntu_14.04/" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/test_repo.list'
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install test
  ```

#### 5. to remove

```
sudo dpkg -P test
```

Comment: @Melebius, done :)